# Can’t login to GUI but can on tty

Tags: kubuntu, login, sddm

I use Kubuntu. I can’t login to GUI but can on tty mode, I check the log and it show this log:

```
invalid session "/var/lib/sddm/.desktop"
```

The output of `journalctl -xe`:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Any change in your system before it stopped working? Please post a better pic of your log (with those lines related with sddm).

As is recommended in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=228373) post, you could try `startx` or move `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to a backup file, if the issue is caused by a misconfiguration of the configuration file.